# Using different functions to calculate ascending and descending values in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a vector with values that describe moisture over time. 
As a result, the values ascend, then descend, then ascend again and it goes on like this...
I need to calculate something, but I need to use a different equation for ascending and descending values.

For example, if I have the following vector:

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 5 6 7 8 5 4 2 1]
```

How can I define that the first 5 values are calculated with equation *f1*, for the next 3 values with *f2*, for the next 4 values with *f1* and the last 4 values again with *f2* ?

Comment: hint-> if you use `diff`, and then `sign`, you can see the "up" and "down" directions easily.

Comment: another way is to use the `findpeaks` to find the local maximum/minimums(by multiplying your equation by -1) and use the indexes.

Comment: What is the expected behavior if the value does not change? Can you provide the desired output for your `A`? For example use _f1=x*10_ and _f2=x*100_ so we can see based on which entries/differences the function needs to be chosen.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will give you the indices you have to solve with f1 and f2

```
A = [0 A]
SolveF1 = find(diff(A)>0)
SolveF2 = find(diff(A)<0)
```

the answer is

```
>> find(diff(A)>0)

ans =

     1     2     3     4     5     9    10    11    12

>> find(diff(A)<0)

ans =

     6     7     8    13    14    15    16
```